# Unable to load page to webview

Tags: java, javafx

I have been on line since morning trying to load one particular page to webview in javafx. Each time I try it shows me

> Browser Error
>
> You're using an older browser that doesn't pass security checks. Please use a newer browser

```html
WebView wv = new WebView();
  wv.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {

   @Override
   public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures p) {
    Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    WebView wv2 = new WebView();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(wv2));
    stage.show();
    return wv2.getEngine();
   }
  });

  StackPane root = new StackPane();
  root.getChildren().add(wv);
   Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
  Scene scene = new Scene(root);

  primaryStage.setTitle("ONE YEAR PLAN");
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
  wv.getEngine().load("http://paystack.com/pay/one_year_plan");
```

I keep on getting this message
[error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSbTW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to stick my neck out and say that it isn't going to be possible to successfully load this page in a JavaFX `WebView`.

The page served up at paystack.com makes a call to `https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check` to check the browser's SSL settings.  Navigating to this URL in Chrome returns a JSON object containing information about Chrome's SSL support.  Attempting to access the same URL with the JavaFX `WebView` returns a 404 error.  The PayStack page then catches the 404 error and shows the warning message you see.

I can't blame PayStack for wanting to lock down their site.  Many other financial institutions will do the same.  I'm also not surprised to see limitations in a web-browser component in a GUI: in my experience these are never as fully-functional as a 'proper' web browser.

Sorry, but I suspect you will have to give up on this one.

Comment: Thanks @Luke Woodward for the reply. What would you recommended me to do as an alternative solution to what am trying to achieve.

Comment: @solomonogbodo: other than trying to load a certain web page in a JavaFX web view, I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in JavaFX, but we do something similar with a java.net.URLConnection in our Swing application. We were getting the same response and this was the fix.
Try calling:
        wv.getEngine().setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36");